# Autoscaling of the Ray node type worker nodes

Tags: python, kubernetes, ray

I have a ray cluster in kubernetes installed using ray operator. The details are as follow:

Ray Operator Image: rayproject/ray:1.11.0-py38

Ray master and worker Image: rayproject/ray:1.11.0-py38

I have created ray cluster with 1 headtype node and worker type with 0 to 50 Nodes. I can see that all the compute happens in the ray headtype node and even if the head resources is fully consumed, no worker node is created by kubernetes operator. Even if i set the resources count to 0 on head type node, actors/jobs are in pending state while no worker type node is created.

Here is the manifest used to create the ray cluster.

```
apiVersion: cluster.ray.io/v1
kind: RayCluster
metadata:
  name: ray-staging
  namespace: staging
spec:
  headPodType: rayHeadType
  headStartRayCommands:
    - ray stop
    - pip install tqdm colorthief ray
    - ulimit -n 65536; ray start --head --port=6379 --no-monitor  --dashboard-host 0.0.0.0
  idleTimeoutMinutes: 3
  maxWorkers: 100
  podTypes:
    - maxWorkers: 0
      minWorkers: 0
      name: rayHeadType
      podConfig:
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Pod
        metadata:
          generateName: ray-head-type-
        spec:
          containers:
            - args:
                - "trap : TERM INT; sleep infinity & wait;"
              command:
                - /bin/bash
                - '-c'
                - '--'
              image: >-
                rayproject/ray:1.11.0-py38
              imagePullPolicy: Always
              name: ray-node
              ports:
                - containerPort: 6379
                  protocol: TCP
                - containerPort: 10001
                  protocol: TCP
                - containerPort: 8265
                  protocol: TCP
                - containerPort: 8000
                  protocol: TCP
              resources:
                limits:
                  cpu: 2
                  memory: 2Gi
                requests:
                  cpu: 2
                  memory: 2Gi
              volumeMounts:
                - mountPath: /dev/shm
                  name: dshm
                - name: images
                  mountPath: /images
          restartPolicy: Never
          volumes:
            - emptyDir:
                medium: Memory
              name: dshm
            - name: images
              persistentVolumeClaim:
                claimName: ray-storage-claim
      rayResources:
        CPU: 2
    - maxWorkers: 50
      minWorkers: 0
      name: rayWorkerType
      podConfig:
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Pod
        metadata:
          generateName: ray-worker-type-
        spec:
            - args:
                - "trap : TERM INT; sleep infinity & wait;"
              command:
                - /bin/bash
                - '-c'
                - '--'
              image: >-
                rayproject/ray:1.11.0-py38
              imagePullPolicy: Always
              name: ray-node
              ports:
                - containerPort: 6379
                  protocol: TCP
                - containerPort: 10001
                  protocol: TCP
                - containerPort: 8265
                  protocol: TCP
                - containerPort: 8000
                  protocol: TCP
              resources:
                limits:
                  cpu: 1
                  memory: 2Gi
                requests:
                  cpu: 1
                  memory: 2Gi
              volumeMounts:
                - mountPath: /dev/shm
                  name: dshm
                - name: images
                  mountPath: /images
          restartPolicy: Never
          volumes:
            - emptyDir:
                medium: Memory
              name: dshm
            - name: images
              persistentVolumeClaim:
                claimName: ray-storage-claim
      rayResources:
        CPU: 2
  upscalingSpeed: 2
  workerStartRayCommands:
    - ray stop
    - pip install tqdm colorthief ray
    - ulimit -n 65536; ray start --address=$RAY_HEAD_IP:6379
```